# How to test for a series of equal X paired rows in a row referring to a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Consider this table @t (TOP 20 of ORDER BY PK DESC):

```
PK  SK  VC  APP     M   C
==  ==  ==  ====    ==  ==================
21  7   79  NULL    0   NULL
20  9   74  1       3   20=14, 18=13, 15=2
19  6   79  1       2   19=11, 17=7
18  9   77  1       0   NULL
17  6   74  1       0   NULL
16  7   79  1       0   NULL
15  9   74  1       0   NULL
14  9   74  1       0   NULL
13  9   77  1       0   NULL
12  7   77  1       0   NULL
11  6   79  1       0   NULL
10  7   79  1       0   NULL
9   7   74  1       0   NULL
8   7   79  1       0   NULL
7   6   74  1       0   NULL
6   6   74  1       0   NULL
5   7   79  1       0   NULL
4   7   77  1       0   NULL
3   6   79  1       0   NULL
2   9   74  1       0   NULL
```

Created with this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, SK INT NOT NULL, VC INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);

INSERT @t (SK,VC,APP,M,C) VALUES
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,2,'19=11, 17=7'),
(9,74,1,3,'20=14, 18=13, 15=2'),
(7,79,NULL,0,NULL)
```

My task is to return `true` for a match if the latest row (`where APP IS NOT NULL`) 
complete a series of X matching pairs or latest rows of the same group (same current SK).

For example, when testing for only 2 pairs, given the current required test is on SK=6, as soon as getting to PK = 19 there is a match.

The match is VC(19)=VC(11)=79 AND VC(17)=VC(7)=74

See that by executing the following:

```
DECLARE @PairsToTest int = 2
DECLARE @SK int = 6
SELECT 
    TOP (2*@PairsToTest) 
    * 
    FROM @t 
    WHERE 
            APP IS NOT NULL 
        AND SK = @SK 
    ORDER BY SK, PK DESC
```

results:

```
PK  SK  VC  APP M   C
19  6   79  1   2   19=11, 17=7
17  6   74  1   0   NULL
11  6   79  1   0   NULL
7   6   74  1   0   NULL
```

Another example:

When testing for 3 pairs, a match is found on PK=20 when looking in SK=9
(Although it is interesting question by itself, for my task there is no need to test for all SKs. A result for a given SK is sufficient for me.

To see the match execute this:

```
DECLARE @PairsToTest int = 3
DECLARE @SK int = 9
SELECT 
    TOP (2*@PairsToTest) 
    * 
    FROM @t 
    WHERE 
            APP IS NOT NULL 
        AND SK = @SK 
    ORDER BY SK, PK DESC
```

which results:

```
PK  SK  VC  APP M   C
20  9   74  1   3   20=14, 18=13, 15=2
18  9   77  1   0   NULL
15  9   74  1   0   NULL
14  9   74  1   0   NULL
13  9   77  1   0   NULL
2   9   74  1   0   NULL
```

as you can see: VC(20)=VC(14)=74, VC(18)=VC(13)=74 and VC(15)=VC(2)

I thought of selecting the required sets of rows in the correct order, and count the equal rows in VC. If the count is the same as the `@PairsToTest` this is the sign to raise a flag.

I tried:

```
DECLARE @PairsToTest int = 3
DECLARE @SK int = 9
;with t0 as
(
SELECT 
    TOP (2*@PairsToTest) 
    * 
    FROM @t 
    WHERE 
            APP IS NOT NULL 
        AND SK = @SK 
    ORDER BY SK, PK DESC
),
t1 AS
(
SELECT TOP (@PairsToTest) * FROM t0
),
t2 AS
(
SELECT TOP (@PairsToTest) * FROM t0 ORDER BY PK ASC 
)
,t3 AS
(
SELECT TOP 99999999 * FROM t2 ORDER BY PK DESC
)

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.VC = t3.VC) = @PairsToTest 
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

but there are too  may flaws in this:

1. VC does not contain unique data (only by chance)
2. the IF is not allowed
3. I should get rid of the TOP 99999999 in t3 (although I can live with that)

What are the required changes I should take in order to solve this?

Comment: You just gave me a headache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, SK INT NOT NULL, VC INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);

INSERT @t (SK,VC,APP,M,C) VALUES
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,2,'19=11, 17=7'),
(9,74,1,3,'20=14, 18=13, 15=2'),
(7,79,NULL,0,NULL)


DECLARE @PairsToTest int = 3
DECLARE @SK int = 9

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t WHERE APP IS NOT NULL AND SK = @SK)-@PairsToTest) >=0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @swapData  TABLE(PK1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, PK INT NOT NULL, SK INT NOT NULL, VC INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);
        DECLARE @olderData TABLE(PK2 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, PK INT NOT NULL, SK INT NOT NULL, VC2 INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);
        DECLARE @newerData TABLE(PK3 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, PK INT NOT NULL, SK INT NOT NULL, VC3 INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);


        INSERT @swapData  SELECT TOP ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t WHERE APP IS NOT NULL AND SK = @SK)-@PairsToTest) * FROM @t WHERE APP IS NOT NULL AND SK = @SK ORDER BY PK
        INSERT @olderData SELECT TOP (@PairsToTest) PK,SK,VC,APP,M,C FROM @swapData ORDER BY PK1 DESC
        INSERT @newerData SELECT TOP (@PairsToTest) * FROM @t WHERE APP IS NOT NULL AND SK = @SK ORDER BY SK, PK DESC



        DECLARE @Matches int = (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @newerData INNER JOIN @olderData ON PK2 = PK3 WHERE VC2=VC3)

        IF @Matches = @PairsToTest 
            SELECT 1 AS Match 
        ELSE 
            SELECT 0 AS Match
    END
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS Match

/*
SELECT TOP (2*@PairsToTest) * FROM @t WHERE APP IS NOT NULL AND SK = @SK ORDER BY SK, PK DESC
SELECT * FROM @olderData
SELECT * FROM @newerData
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it counts number of row pairs in each of the SK partitions and excludes rows without a pair from the result:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, SK INT NOT NULL, VC INT NULL,  APP INT NULL, M INT NOT NULL,  C NVARCHAR(111) NULL);

INSERT @t (SK,VC,APP,M,C) VALUES
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,0,NULL),
(7,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,74,1,0,NULL),
(7,79,1,0,NULL),
(6,74,1,0,NULL),
(9,77,1,0,NULL),
(6,79,1,2,'19=11, 17=7'),
(9,74,1,3,'20=14, 18=13, 15=2'),
(7,79,NULL,0,NULL)

;WITH c AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SK ORDER BY VC DESC) DenseRankPartitionBySK,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SK ORDER BY PK DESC) ordinalNumberInSKPartition
    FROM    @t
    WHERE   APP IS NOT NULL
),
e AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SK, DenseRankPartitionBySK) _Sum,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SK, DenseRankPartitionBySK ORDER BY PK) Odd
    FROM    c
),
d AS (
    SELECT  *,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SK) numberOfRows
    FROM    e 
    WHERE   _Sum % 2 = 0 OR Odd <> 1
)

SELECT  
        d.PK, d.SK, d.VC, d.APP, d.M, d.C, 
        CASE WHEN ordinalNumberInSKPartition = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsTopRow,
        numberOfRows / 2 [NumberOfPairsInSKPartition(M)]
FROM    d
ORDER   BY SK, PK DESC
```